# Issue with onClick in React component

Tags: onclick, reactjs

I have a search result component that contains a div that, when clicked, is supposed to open a modal. Here's the relevant code below:

```js
const createClickableDiv = function(props){
  if(props.searchType === 'option1'){
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onDivClick}>
       <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
    );
  }else if(props.searchType === 'option2'){
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onDivClick}>
       <div>Some other content</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (<div className="result-empty"></div>);
};



class SearchResultItem extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  onDivClick(){
    AppUIActions.openModal((<Modal />));
  }
  render(){
    const clickableDiv = createClickableDiv(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        {clickableDiv}
      </div>
  }
}
```

When I load the page, nothing shows up. However, when I remove `onClick={this.onDivClick}` from the divs, everything renders correctly, just without the desired click functionality. I put a try-catch around the code in the createClickableDiv function and it's saying `this` is undefined. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.` sometimes behaves strangely. When your function createClickableDiv is called, `this` no longer refers to your SearchResultItem but to the createClickableDiv, which does not have the function onDivClick defined.

Try changing the function call to `createClickableDiv(this)`, to pass pointer to your complete SearchResultItem,
and change the function itself to:

```
const createClickableDiv = function(caller){
  if(caller.props.searchType === 'option1'){
    return (
      <div onClick={caller.onDivClick}>
       <div>Some content</div>
      </div>
      // etc..
```

Maybe that would work.